# Definir Rotulo do evento do Google Analytics

Tags: eventos, google-analytics-api

boa noite..

Estou configurando os eventos dos formularios do site para ser monitorado pelo Analytics.
Mas apenas um que eu não consigo fazer da maneira que eu quero.. 
Que é pegar o rotulo pelo campo do select,  por exemplo:

```
<form  action="envia_orca.php" onSubmit="ga('send', 'event', 'interesse','Solicitar orçamento para', {plano});" method="POST">

<select type="plano" id="plano" name="plano" class="form-control">
    <option value="plano 1">Plano 1</option>
    <option value="plano 2">Plano 2</option>
    <option value="plano 3">Plano 3</option>
</select>
```

Eu queria que rótulo do GA, fosse definido pelo campo "plano" do formulário, como posso fazer isso?

Muito obrigada..

Answer (score 0):

Basta você trocar `'interesse'` pelo valor do select no momento do submit:

```
<form  action="envia_orca.php" onSubmit="ga('send', 'event', document.getElementById('plano').value,'Solicitar orçamento para', {plano});" method="POST">
```